# Libraries to parse email into json, like what mailgun is doing

Tags: python, json, email, mime, mailgun

I'm looking for library that can parse email content into a json (or any structured data format). I know there are a number of services like mailgun providing this but I prefer to use my own email server and pass the email directly into my python script rather than having to expose another HTTP endpoint to receive json from service like mailgun. I have a number of side projects that accepting input through email and right now the processing is done in each project using the email module in standard lib. I plan to consolidate all the email processing into a single libraries so that each project only need to deal with json, instead of email format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We just open sourced our small python script to parse incoming mail to JSON and do a POST callback to a remote URL.

More details here:
https://github.com/Newsman/MailToJson

Comment: It turned out that Mailgun also has open sourced their email parsing library !

https://github.com/mailgun/talon
http://blog.mailgun.com/open-sourcing-our-email-signature-parsing-library/

Comment: An update for 2016. Mailgun has open sourced their [`flanker`](https://github.com/mailgun/flanker) email parsing library (for Python 2.7 currently). It's significantly faster and more memory efficient than the Python standard library [`email`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/email.html) package. Here's the [user manual](https://github.com/mailgun/flanker/blob/master/docs/User%20Manual.md) with common examples of parsing headers and mime parts. @k4ml's comment mentions [`talon`](https://github.com/mailgun/talon), which is a library for extracting message quotations and signatures.

Comment: for me parsing the email with https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mail-parser worked best